# Como hago para limitar al usuario a poner un marcador por hora en Android studio?

Tags: android, google-maps

Muy buenas
Estoy trabajando en una app en Android studio en la que debo mostrar un mapa. Aqui el usuario debe de tener la opcion de tocar un boton y poder agregar un marcador en el mapa a la vez que tocar un boton y poder eliminar dicho marcador.
Aparte de esto el usuario se le debera dejar agregar un marcador por hora.
Para este problema se me ha ocurrido una sola solucion. Dicha solucion es la siguiente:
Cada vez que el usuario agrega un marcador, un boton de eliminacion aparece y el boton de agregado desaparece. De forma analoga sucede si toco el boton de eliminado. El problema es que no logre hacer desaparecer el boton de agregado, lo cual hace que el usuario pueda agregar mas de un marcador.
Este es mi codigo:

```
 public Marker addMarker(Location location){
        if(mMap != null && location != null){
            LatLng gps = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
            marker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(gps));
            marker.setDraggable(true);
            return marker;
        }
        return null;
    }

    public void drawMarker(View view){
        Location loc = returnLocation();
        marker = addMarker(loc);
        dialogPlayas.dismiss();
        removeMarker = findViewById(R.id.remove);
        removeMarker.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        dialogPlayas = findViewById(R.id.addMarker);
        addMarker.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        Handler markerHandler = new Handler();
        markerHandler.postDelayed(timeRemoveMarker,3600000); //van a durar ua hora osea 3600000 milisegundos
    }

    private Runnable timeRemoveMarker = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            addMarker.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            marker.remove();
        }
    };



    public void removeMarkerButton(View view) {
        if (marker != null) {
            marker.remove();
            addMarker.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            removeMarker.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }
```

Como ven el boton de eliminado aparece en mi actividad principal (mapa) pero el de agregado en un dialogo de alerta que se llama desde el mapa. El problema es que cada vez que toco en el, el mismo no desaparece y eso que el de eliminado si. Alguna sugerencia? Estoy hace dias con este problema.

Answer (score 1):

Toma la referencias del botón del método:

```
public void drawMarker(View view){
        Button addMarker = (Button)view;
        addMarker.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        Location loc = returnLocation();
        marker = addMarker(loc);
        dialogPlayas.dismiss();
        removeMarker = findViewById(R.id.remove);
        removeMarker.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        dialogPlayas = findViewById(R.id.addMarker);

        Handler markerHandler = new Handler();
        markerHandler.postDelayed(timeRemoveMarker,3600000); //van a durar ua hora osea 3600000 milisegundos
    }
```

Otra razón que puede estar pasando es que tu handler este haciendo visible tu botón nuevamente cuando lanza el hilo y ejecuta:

```
 addMarker.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta voy a intentar esto y te digo como me va !